# Pitch calculation from quaternion

Tags: ios, objective-c, quaternions, glkit, pitch

In the function below I'm trying to calculate pitch from GLKQuaternion:

```
    float panX = asinf(2.0f * (quaternion.z*quaternion.x - quaternion.w*quaternion.y));
    return panX;
```

It seems like it's working fine, but there's one problem. If I understood corectly, pitch it's basically the angle, and in my case once it reaches value of 90 degrees (no matter if it's positive or negative), value of pitch starts to slowly decrease. And it's a big problem, because it seems like that object starts to rotate in opposite side (which is not).

How can I extend the range of calculated pitch from `[-90, 90]`?

Comment: 1. You can use conversion to Euler angles from your math library.
2. You can transform the "DIR" vector, and estimate the angle with ground plane.

it depends on what you expect

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer! 1) GLKQuaternion doesn't provide euler angles, I have to calculate by myself, and when I did it, I've got the same result (once angle reaches 90 degrees, it starts to decrease) As for 2) Can you clarify what should I do? I didn't understand how to do it.